# Check conditions in XSLT

Tags: xslt

I want to check condition using xslt. There is a node called `tps:c` and there are different `@type` in that node as a attribute. There are several attributes types, and I want to skip those types. There are several types, I want to copy them. I used following code to do this. But not successful.

Tried code :

```
<xsl:template match="tps:row/tps:entry/tps:p/tps:c" priority="100">
    <xsl:variable name="c.type">
        <map input="_Table Blue grid ALL" output="_Table Blue grid ALL"/>
        <map input="_Table Light Blue grid ALL" output="_Table Light Blue grid ALL"/>
        <map input="_Table Light Blue" output="_Table Light Blue"/>
        <map input="_Table Green grid ALL" output="_Table Green grid ALL"/>
        <map input="_Table Light Green ALL" output="_Table Light Green ALL"/>
        <map input="_Table Yellow grid ALL" output="_Table Yellow grid ALL"/>
        <map input="_Table Orange grid ALL" output="_Table Orange grid ALL"/>
        <map input="_Table Red grid ALL" output="_Table Red grid ALL"/>
        <map input="_Table Light Grey grid ALL" output="_Table Light Grey grid ALL"/>
        <map input="_Table Light Grey" output="_Table Light Grey"/>
        <map input="_Table grid ALL" output="_Table grid ALL"/>
        <map input="_Table grid TOP" output="_Table grid TOP"/>
        <map input="_Table grid TOP-RIGHT" output="_Table grid TOP-RIGHT"/>
        <map input="_Table grid TOP-BOTTOM" output="_Table grid TOP-BOTTOM"/>
        <map input="_Table grid TOP-LEFT" output="_Table grid TOP-LEFT"/>
        <map input="_Table grid RIGHT" output="_Table grid RIGHT"/>
        <map input="_Table grid LEFT" output="_Table grid LEFT"/>
        <map input="_Table grid BOTTOM" output="_Table grid BOTTOM"/>
        <map input="_Table Light Grey Last" output="_Table Light Grey Last"/>
        <map input="_Table Light Blue Last" output="_Table Light Blue Last"/>
        <map input="_Table grid BOTTOM-LEFT" output="_Table grid BOTTOM-LEFT"/>
        <map input="_Table grid BOTTOM-RIGHT" output="_Table grid BOTTOM-RIGHT"/>
        <map input="_Table Light Green grid ALL" output="_Table Light Green grid ALL"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="p.type" select="parent::tps:p/tps:c/@type"/>
    <xsl:variable name="output.type" select="$c.type/map[@input=$p.type]/@output"/>

    <xsl:variable name="type2" select="$output.type"/>

    <xsl:if test="self::tps:c[@type != $type2]">
        <xsl:copy-of select="self::tps:c"/>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

As above I tried to use `map` and check current type is equal or not to mentioned types.

Input :

```
<tps:row>
   <tps:entry align="left" namest="1" valign="middle">
       <tps:p type="Table Body"/>
   </tps:entry>
   <tps:entry align="left" namest="2" valign="top">
       <tps:p type="Table Body">EWS</tps:p>
   </tps:entry>
   <tps:entry align="left" namest="3" valign="top">
       <tps:p type="Table Body">207<tps:c type="TB_CHAR">.</tps:c> 
       </tps:p>
   </tps:entry>
  <tps:entry align="left" namest="4" valign="top">
     <tps:p type="Table Body">295<tps:c type="TB_CHAR">.</tps:c> . 
     </tps:p>
     <tps:p type="Table Body">295<tps:c type="_Table Light Blue">. 
     </tps:c></tps:p>
  </tps:entry>
</row>
```

Output should be:

```
<tps:row>
   <tps:entry align="left" namest="1" valign="middle">
       <tps:p type="Table Body"/>
   </tps:entry>
   <tps:entry align="left" namest="2" valign="top">
       <tps:p type="Table Body">EWS</tps:p>
   </tps:entry>
   <tps:entry align="left" namest="3" valign="top">
       <tps:p type="Table Body">207<tps:c type="TB_CHAR">.</tps:c> 
       </tps:p>
   </tps:entry>
  <tps:entry align="left" namest="4" valign="top">
     <tps:p type="Table Body">295<tps:c type="TB_CHAR">.</tps:c> . 
     </tps:p>
     <tps:p type="Table Body">295</tps:p>
  </tps:entry>
</row>
```

Comment: you can try this <xsl:variable name="p.type" select="//tps:p/tps:c/@type"/>

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear why you want such "map", but it looks like you are stripping `tps:c` elements having `type` attribute that match some blacklist.

From variable declaration it seems your are using XSLT 2.0+. So, you need to declare the variable as top level with global scope and then use this simple template with a transformation that use the overriding identity template pattern:

```
<xsl:template match="tps:c[@type = $c.type/map/@input]" priority="100"/>
```

Check it [here](https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bFN1yak)

If you need an explicit "allow/deny" flow, then you could just use these templates:

```
<xsl:template match="tps:c[@type = $c.type/map/@input]" priority="100"/>

<xsl:template match="tps:c[not(@type = $c.type/map/@input)]" priority="100">
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>
```

Check it [here](https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/ej9EGdn)